# Checking if FTP directory Exists error

Tags: c#, linq, ssis

I have an ftp script task in SSIS where I am checking to see if a directory called "Home" exists. If it does I am using that directory. If it doesn't I don't want to use that directory. It works fine when the Home directory exists, but throws an error when it doesn't.
I'm pretty sure it is throwing an error here.

```
if (strFolders.Any(strHomedir.Contains))
```

[] Error: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at ST_eaa7bc4824c348d1ad678ec3ceec2a33.ScriptMain.Main()

Any help is appreciated.

```
ConnectionManager ftpManager = null;
        FtpClientConnection ftpConnection = null;
        string[] strFolders = null;
        string[] strFiles = null;
        string strHomedir = "Home";
        string strFTPPassword = Dts.Variables["$Project::FTP_Password"].GetSensitiveValue().ToString();
        string strRemotePath = Dts.Variables["strFTPDirectory"].Value.ToString();
        string localfile = Dts.Variables["strIQRFileName"].Value.ToString();
        string[] localfilearray = new string[] { localfile };

        try
        {
            ftpManager = Dts.Connections["FTPServer"];
            ftpConnection = new FtpClientConnection(ftpManager.AcquireConnection(null));
            ftpConnection.ServerPassword = strFTPPassword;
            ftpConnection.Connect();
            ftpConnection.SetWorkingDirectory(strRemotePath);
            ftpConnection.GetListing(out strFolders, out strFiles);
            if (strFolders.Any(strHomedir.Contains))
            {
                strRemotePath = strRemotePath + "/" + strHomedir;
            }
            ftpConnection.SendFiles(localfilearray, strRemotePath, true, false);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Dts.Events.FireError(-1, string.Empty, ex.ToString(), string.Empty, 0);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }
        finally
        {
            ftpConnection = null;
            ftpManager = null;
        }
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Comment: The exception is because `strFolders` is null. Look inside method `GetListing` or paste the code here.

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to help. I added if (strFolders == null || strFolders.Length == 0) and it seems to be working correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `strFolder` is null. Check the value before passing it to the method:

```
if (strFolders != null && strFolders.Any(strHomedir.Contains))
{
}
```